# Using Python range and calendar to check for leap year

Tags: python, python-2.7

Noob question. Is there a more ideal way to express a range using both range and calendar. Looking to set up a print True if any of the years in my range are leap years

```
year =  calendar.isleap(range(2016,2036))



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/calendar.py", line 99, in isleap
return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions are good for this

```
leap_years = [year for year in range(2016, 2036) if calendar.isleap(year)]
```

As are filters, if you prefer the map/reduce/filter way of doing things

```
leap_years = filter(calendar.isleap, range(2016, 2036))
```

The former should be preferred unless you have good reason to use `filter` (hint: you probably don't)

N.B. that this gives you which years are leap years (if any), rather than a boolean "There are leap years" or "There aren't leap years." See fuglede's [excellent answer using `any`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877754/3058609) for a boolean response.

Comment: this would also be interesting: `leap_years = any(calendar.isleap(year) for year in range(2016, 2036))` since it returns `True` as the OP mentions

Comment: you can also get the `bool(leap_years)` for a boolean answer since empty lists return False while lists with elements return True.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to make use of the Python [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in;

```
In [1]: import calendar

In [2]: test1 = any(calendar.isleap(y) for y in range(2016, 2036))

In [3]: test2 = any(calendar.isleap(y) for y in range(2097, 2103))

In [4]: print(test1)
True

In [5]: print(test2)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic way

```
>>> import calendar
>>> any(map(calendar.isleap, range(2016, 2036)))
True
```